# Defining a function to filter a dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: bmg and etext.

```
bmg = pd.DataFrame({''product_title':['%macroeconomics 101','Physics','Calculus'], 
                'author':['Abel', 'Jenkins', 'Williams'], 
                'isbn13':['1238404589228', '1238404589235', '123840458432']})
bmg


etext = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['Macroeconomics','History','Anatomy'], 
                'Author':['Abel', 'Jenkins', 'Franklin']})

etext
```

I'm wanting to filter the bmg set to only include matching values in the etext dataframe (i.e. have the same author and title as listed in the etext dataframe). Here's the challenge: the "product_title" in the bmg set sometimes has extra characters, so it won't be a direct match. I would like it to be a str.contains.

If I do something like this:

```
find = 'Macroeconomics'
test = df[df['product_title'].str.contains(find, case=False, na=False)]
test
```

The filter works, but of course I filter out other rows in etext I want. I need to run on both columns across the entire etext dataframe.

Expected output for bmg:

```
pd.DataFrame({''product_title':['%macroeconomics 101], 
                'author':['Abel'], 
                'isbn13':['1238404589228']})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind posting a minimal (but significative) working example? Input and expected output.

Comment: Hi Riccardo - Thank you for your response. I've added screenshots of the dataframes. My expected output is simply a filtered bmg dataframe which contains all the str.contains for the etext columns. So, for example, I'd like it to filter for all rows that have "Abel" as the author and "Macroeconomics" in the "product_title". Even if the "product_title" says: "%Macroeconomics 101"

Comment: Please post the code we need to create those dataframes. Also, what is the desired output? That's the most important part. Try to build two input dataframes and and output one, and post them here so that we can validate our solutions

Comment: Hi again - I made edits that I hope are helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try just merging the dataframes and removing the lines that don't match your rule:

```
df = pd.merge(etext, bmg, left_on='Author', right_on='author')

df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Title'] in x['product_title'], axis=1)]
```

Then you could transform the Title into the index if they are all different

```
df = df.set_index('Title')
df.loc['Macroeconomics']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that the name of the authors and titles are not always a direct match. If etext has "Microeconomics" and bmg has "%Microeconomics" the above could wouldn't work.

Comment: You said only titles would differ. That above works exactly for the case you just pointed out if etext has "Microeconomics" and bmg has "%Microeconomics"